# boost::lockfree::queue allowed data structure example?

Tags: c++, boost, queue, lock-free

boost::lockfree::queue has some recuirements for data structure to be queued

- trivial copy constructor
- trivial assignment
- trivial destructor

Please, give an example of such class

Comment: Maybe, You need use raw pointer (new and delete).

Answer (score 0):

Obvious examples would be essentially any POD class:

```
struct point { 
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Obviously, the number and *exact* types of members don't matter much as long as each of them is itself either a built-in type like `int`, or else some other type the meets the requirements.